# Parse eventually crashes on android

Tags: android, parsing, notifications

well i have one problem with parse, but i can´t know why it crashes, i explain it.

Im working with parse, and works ok, but then with no reason, sometimes, when i turn off the mobile or go out of the wifi´s range, the app crashes. i think all its ok, cause i can recieve parse´s notifications with no problem.... well need some help here

The app its a webview

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView myWebView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);


ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveEventually(); 


this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web);

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//iniciamos javascript

myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this),"Android");

//webviewclient para websettings
WebSettings websettings= myWebView.getSettings();
websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.aaaaa.com/);
```

}

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
if(this.myWebView.canGoBack())
    this.myWebView.goBack();
else
    super.onBackPressed();
```

}

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private long loadTime;

@Override 
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.aaaaa.com"))  { 

            return false;
}
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

}



public class ParseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "received " + intent.getAction());
        PushService.startServiceIfRequired(context);
    }
    }


}

}
```

and then the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jor.dietd"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />  

<permission android:name="com.jor.dietd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.jor.xxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jor.xxxxx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
   <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


 <category android:name="com.jor.xxxx" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Switch of the wifi, get the logcat error stack, and add it here after that it will be easier to understand the error, but if i should guess it is in OnRecieve part and the error is nullpointerexception, because the intent is null.

Comment: The problem its not always crashes when i turn off the wifi, so i can´t know when is going to crash...

Comment: how should i mofify it for not getting that intent null? @attels?

Comment: If it is null, the only thing you can do is make a check - if(intent==null){return;} And maybe alert the user that something is gone wrong.